# Get negative thoughts (away from yourself / out of your mind)

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

I was wondering as which one of the following structures sounds more natural to be said to Yoga students by their master?

> **a.** Get negative thoughts away from yourself. 
> **b.** Get negative thoughts out of your mind.

I was wondering if there is any better (more idiomatic / natural) way to imply the same message if my offers do not make a good sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(b) is what people normally say. A fluent speaker would be unlikely to say (a). It's "get negative thoughts out of your mind" or "out of your head".